# is my jquery loading twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I try to use fancybox plugin. I load the plugin after I load jquery. Somehow, I can't get it to work. And, for some reason, Firebug shows 2 identical errors, saying that fancybox is not a function. However, I use the function only once, so why 2 errors? I read somewhere that if jquery is loaded twice it might cause problems. Is that the reason why Firebug shows the error twice? Are my scripts loaded twice? Why? As far as I know, I only load them once, in the head section of my html.

```
enter code here
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>Event List (andy)</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' type='text/css' />
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="logo.ico">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='floor.js'></script>   
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, why are you adding code before your opening `<head>` tag? That's just wrong.

jQuery might not be loaded twice, but if your code is running twice then your code is definitely loaded twice somehow.

My advice is to put a `console.debug('foo');` or a breakpoint in your code where you suspect it's being loaded only once. If you see the `foo` in your console twice, you know your code is, in fact, loading twice. Then, I would figure out what the culprit is, perhaps by performing surgery and cutting chunks out of the page until I find out what's causing it. This is to isolate the problem.

EDIT: It's not working because you're not including the script. Your line says `jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery-1.4.3.min.js` which is loading jquery. You need it to be like `jquery.fancybox.js` instead.

Comment: I am not adding any code before <head> tag. Lol. Why would you say that? I did the breakpoint check, and reloaded the page, the code stopped twice at the breakpoint. So, I am guessing, it is being loaded twice. I have NO IDEA why. And, how about fancybox not working? Could that be the cause?

Comment: The first two lines of your example are `enter code here` and then 
`<head>` which leads me to think you have code above your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Oh, no. I don't know why that thing "add code here" is there.

Comment: i just downloaded the fancybox source and it's on version `2.1.5` so why are you running this older version?

Comment: I think that solved my problem. I downloaded it and assuming that was the script i needed to load, I didn't even look in other folders to see if there are other scripts. They seem to have included jquery script in the folder, and that's why my jquery was loading twice, cuz what i thought was fancybox script was actually another jquery script. And yes, I already got the newest version. Thank you for your help